# Remove encryption key set for a file in vim

Tags: vim

I have mistakenly save one of my files with :X command and hence I had to set my encryption key for that. But now I want to remove the encryption key and keep it as it was. I tried setting `:set key=` found on internet. But nothing seems work.
To be precise, may be I am missing any steps.
Can anyone please help with the steps? I mean what to do and how, please?

Answer (score 4):

The user who asked this probably missed the step of saving the newly un-encrypted file *after* using `set key=`

`:w` or `:wq` to save or save and exit.